# SpecFlow: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I was getting the following error when running my tests using SpecFlow:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

And it took me a while to work out why it was happening.

Comment: I've got the same error, and the complete lack of helpful stack trace (or any clue as to where it's happening) from SpecFlow doesn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It ended up being because I had omitted the single quotes in one of my step definitions, for example:

```
[Then(@"Something adds up to a quantity of (.*)")]
```

when it should have been

```
[Then(@"Something adds up to a quantity of '(.*)'")]
```

Note the single quotes around (.*)

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to look for when running into this problem is to verify parameters.

```
When I update the thing by Id (<Id>)

Examples:
  | Name |
  | 1    |
```

The problem here is that "Id" does not match "Name" in the examples table

Answer (score 0):

This may be INDEED a very time consuming issue, particulary when debugging step-by-step and only getting the `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format` when we get thru the last scenario line, although the offending binding code was related to a prior one.

In my case, I had initialy created a feature with several integers, which generated feature **StepDefinitions** code using **INT** parameters, and they runned fine. However, later, I've decide to test an edge case with a decimal value, but I forgot to revise feature **StepDefinitions** code according, namelly changing some parameters from **INT** to **DECIMAL**. That's when I run into troubles.

### The feature

```
Feature: Calculator

Finds de differente between two numbers

Scenario: Subtract two numbers
    Given the first number is 12.5
    And the second number is 2.5
    When the two numbers are subtracted
    Then the result should be 10
```

## The feature StepDefinitions's code

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace ProcessamentoTests.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public class CalculatorStepDefinitions
    {
        [Given(@"the first number is (.*)")]
        public void GivenTheFirstNumberIs(decimal p0)
        {
            // Ignore for now
        }

        [Given(@"the second number is (.*)")]
        public void GivenTheSecondNumberIs(int p0)
        {
            // Ignore for now
        }

        [When(@"the two numbers are subtracted")]
        public void WhenTheTwoNumbersAreSubtracted()
        {
            // Ignore for now
        }

        [Then(@"the result should be (.*)")]
        public void ThenTheResultShouldBe(int p0)
        {
            // Ignore for now
        }
    }
}
```

## The solution is...

In this case, both **p0** parameters on **GivenTheSecondNumberIs** and **ThenTheResultShouldBe** should be changed do **DECIMAL** type.

Therefore, until **Specflow's** team (*) manages a way to provide better context on parameter parsing issues, **all scenario parameter bindings should be revised**.

(*) Bear in mind that, given Specflow is a beloved open source project, everyone (including me) may be part of its team.